# Android - Alarm para celular de acordo com o a hora do sistema

Tags: java, android, android-alarmmanager

Olá.

Eu pesquisei muito e já aprendi a fazer algumas coisas bacanas com o AlarmManager e outras coisas do tipo. Eu queria fazer um despertador para meu celular para testes, o problema é que todos os códigos e tutoriais que eu encontro é para despertar daqui a certo tempo, mesmo que seja para desperta depois de 24 hrs não sei se é o ideal.

Eu não queria algo que o alarmasse depois de um certo tempo, eu gostaria de saber como eu faço um alarme que ele ative de acordo com o horário do sistema, isto é, se for pra ele ser ativo as 23:55 então é sempre neste horário, não importa se a pessoa desativar o aplicativo ou se ela avançar o horário do sistema.

Como todo alarme que eu encontrei, há um broadcast que é ativo depois de um certo tempo. Eu pensei em fazer com que esse broadcast tivesse uma nova trhead com um while verificando a cada minuto o horário do sistema para ver se é de acordo com o que a pessoa colocou. Isso funcionaria ? Porque caso funcione eu acho que isso deve consumir muita bateria, imagina um While rodando durante 24 hrs ?

Como posso fazer isso, alguém pode me ajudar ?
Desde já eu agradeço :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer um alarme que se repita deverá usar um dos seguintes métodos do AlarmManager: [setInexactRepeating()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) ou [setRepeating()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29).

Em ambos são o segundo e o terceiro parâmetro que informam quando e com que periodicidade o alarme é lançado.
O segundo parâmetro indica quando e o terceiro a periodicidade.

Assim se, por exemplo quiser um alarme que seja lançado às 8 horas da manhã todos os dias seria algo assim:

```
//Cria um Calendar "setado" para as 8 horas
//para ser passado no segundo parâmetro.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);

//Passa-se a constante AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY ao terceiro parâmetro
//para indicar que a periocidade é diária  
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: Deu pra ter uma ideia, muito obrigado :)

Answer (score 0):

Olha, eu consegui fazer o alarme do jeito que eu precisava desse jeito, usando as seguintes informações:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 48);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

Funciona bem se o usuário não mexer em mais nada. O problema é que ele está com várias falhas.
Se eu deixar do jeito que está, todos os dias as 20:48 exatas ele irá despertar. O problema é se o usuário usar o botão de Parar a aplicação na qual corresponde a

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.cancel(pi);
```

Quando o botão é ativo, o despertador para de funcionar, isto é, se são 20:45 e ele para a aplicação e depois ele usa o Start de novo pra continuar a aplicação, o despertador fica todo perdido, ele já para de despertar as 20:48.

Além disso, fazendo alguns testes aqui, ele só roda uma vez por dia, caso seja dua 17/10 e ele já despertou, mesmo se eu voltar o horário do sistema para as 20:47, quando for 20:48 ele não desperta mais, eu sei que isso é devido ao comando do AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, mas eu não gostaria de usar isso, eu gostaria que apenas despertasse quando desse o horário, simples: hora do celular = 20:48: desperta. Independente do dia ou quantas vezes for.
Será que tem como ?
 O que acontece se eu colocar 0 no lugar do AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY ? Eu testei e só percebi que mesmo se você passar 1 dia depois, ele para de funcionar.

Estou um pouco perdido rsrs

Comment: Não utilize a caixa de resposta para fazer uma pergunta. Se tem uma nova pergunta utilize o botão no canto superior direito da página ou siga este [link.](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)